# Is there any alternative to polymorphism in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I was reading an article on frequently asked Java interview questions, and got stuck on one question: "What is the alternative to polymorphism?"

I searched for it but didn't get any rational answer.

Is there an alternative to polymorphism in Java? If yes, then what is it?

Comment: They were probably after "an Interface".  But might have been after Aggregation or Encapsulation (or frankly, a bunch of other things) depending on context.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Coding to an interface that may have more implementations counts as polymorphism too so isn’t an alternative to polymorphism (if this is what you meant).

Comment: When *polymorphism* means handling different forms without caring about their differences, then the alternative would be handling each form separately, one way or the other, which would lead to (unnecessary) code duplication.

Comment: @OleV.V. Polymorphism is a result of inheritance, where a single object can have more than a single "is-a" relationship with a class.  This is not true of an Interface, however an Interface does still provide a mechanism for an object to implement well defined set of behaviors.  Given that there is no context for the question, and that the question is very short and somewhat ambiguous I'm guessing that's the answer they wanted.  Your comment ("counts as polymorphism") actually reinforces that opinion.  Again, they could have been after many other things.

Comment: It seems your definition of polymorphism differs from mine, @Tibrogargan. It’s OK, few concepts (if any) have a clearcut definition that everyone agrees to.

Comment: While there are many variations of Polymorphism, this is a question about **Java** Polymorphism.  As far as I know, there is only one definition in Java - an object must be a subclass to be polymorphic.  But, knowing there would be differences of opinion about this is precisely why I voted to close this question as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to using polymorphism in Java is to use `instanceof` and type casts.

It is not is *good* alternative ...

Here is an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
   public interface Animal {
       String makeSound();  // polymorphic method ...
   }
   public class Cat implements Animal {
       public String makeSound() { return "meow"; }
   }
   public class Dog implements Animal {
       public String makeSound() { return "woof"; }
   }

   // polymorphic:
   Animal someAnimal = ...
   System.out.println("Animal sound is " + someAnimal.makeSound());

   // non-polymorphic
   if (someAnimal instanceof Cat) {
       System.out.println("Animal sound is " + ((Cat) someAnimal).makeSound()); 
   } else if (someAnimal instanceof Dog) {
       System.out.println("Animal sound is " + ((Dog) someAnimal).makeSound()); 
   }
```

Note that the non-polymorphic version is clearly more verbose.  But the thing is that the non-polymorphic version will work if `Cat` and `Dog` don't have a common interface with a `makeSound()` method.

Comment: Without having a common interface with a common method, how could non-polymorphic version work since in the above example the Cat and Dog are implementing the same interface?

Comment: `Cat` would still have a `makeSound` method, so after casting to `Cat` you can call the method (same for `Dog`). @stuteemishra

Answer (score 1):

It might be a rule of object-oriented programming called composition over inheritance,
which states that an object should achieve polymorphic behavior by containing instances of other classes implementing desired functionalities rather then by inheriting from a parent class.